# Emulate ARM Systems on QEMU

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, qemu, cortex-m

How do I setup QEMU to emulate ARM Cortex M3 system?

I am trying to build a kernel(C and/or assembly) for ARM based chips from the scratch. In order to accomplish that first I must emulate the system itself on QEMU so that I can run my code. The microcontroller I am using is NXP LPC1768(Cortex M3, 512KB Flash, 64KB SRAM , Ethernet).

Would be grateful if someone can help out with this. I do not access to a physical LPC1768 at the moment.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Edited . How to setup QEMU to emulate NXP LPC1768?

Comment: you just run the appropriate qemu command line.  now m3 is supported but is that specific nxp part emulated?  if not then you have to write the emulator for that chip first then just run it.

Comment: This looks helpful: https://github.com/myokota/qemu-cortex-m3

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `qemu-system-arm` command. Adding the `-machine help` arguments currently outputs a list of 111 supported machines. You can fiilter that to only Cortex-M3 machines like this, with the current output:

```
 % qemu-system-arm -machine help | grep Cortex-M3 | grep -v Cortex-M33
lm3s6965evb          Stellaris LM3S6965EVB (Cortex-M3)
lm3s811evb           Stellaris LM3S811EVB (Cortex-M3)
mps2-an385           ARM MPS2 with AN385 FPGA image for Cortex-M3
mps2-an511           ARM MPS2 with AN511 DesignStart FPGA image for Cortex-M3
netduino2            Netduino 2 Machine (Cortex-M3)
stm32vldiscovery     ST STM32VLDISCOVERY (Cortex-M3)
```

I believe the closest option to the NXP chip you're asking about would be the STM32F2 in the `netduino2` machine. Boot your firmware on that machine with:

```
qemu-system-arm -M netduino2 -kernel firmware.bin
```

Here's a relevant page in the qemu docs for more info:
https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/arm/stm32.html

Taking the next step, assuming you want to debug using gdb, a more full example would go as follows. In one terminal, you start the emulation, freezing the CPU at startup with the -S flag:

```
qemu-system-arm -cpu cortex-m3 -machine netduino2 -gdb tcp::3333 -S -nographic -kernel firmware.bin
```

Then in another terminal, start a gdb client:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb firmware.bin
```

Then at the `(gdb)` prompt, connect with:

```
target remote :3333
```